# Scala Play Websocket - use one out actor to send both: Array[Byte] and String messages

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket

I have Play websockets action:

```
def socket = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[String, Array[Byte]] { request => out =>
    Props(new WebSocketInActor(out))
}
```

Generally I need to send to browser large raw arrays of data. But sometimes I need to send some small string data. In browser I can detect is data in text format or raw ArrayBuffer.
If I create actor that sends String, I can send string messages, If I create actor that sends with Array[Byte], I can send raw arrays. Both situations I don't need to change client code. So, how can I force Play to use both sending methods with one out actor?

Comment: maybe you could send to actor this both data and in onMessage check using instance of what kind of type they are. 
ActorRef saver = Akka.system().actorOf(Props.create(YourActor.class));
saver.tell(yourDataToSend, getSelf())

Answer (score 3):

Ah, those answers that comes just after you post question on SO. Looking through reference and sourcecode, I found that there is mixedFrame FrameFromatter: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/WebSocket.scala#L75

So you just need to say that you will respond with Either[String, Array[Byte]] and if you want to send string use Left(somestring) or else use Right[somearray].

```
  class WebSocketInActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
    override def preStart() = {
      println("User connected")
      val s = "Hello"
      out ! Left(s)
      out ! Right(s.getBytes("utf8"))
    }
    override def postStop() = {
      println("User discconnected")
    }
    def receive = {
      case msg: String => {
      }
      case _ =>
    }
  }

  def socket = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[String, Either[String, Array[Byte]]] { request => out =>
    Props(new WebSocketInActor(out))
  }
```

UPDATE:

Or you can go one step further and create your own frame formatter

```
  sealed trait WSMessage
  case class StringMessage(s: String) extends WSMessage
  case class BinaryMessage(a: Array[Byte]) extends WSMessage
  case class JsonMessage(js: JsValue) extends WSMessage

  implicit object myFrameFormatter extends BasicFrameFormatter[WSMessage] {
    private val textFrameClass = classOf[TextFrame]
    private val binaryFrameClass = classOf[BinaryFrame]

    def toFrame(message: WSMessage): BasicFrame = message match {
      case StringMessage(s) => TextFrame(s)
      case BinaryMessage(a) => BinaryFrame(a)
      case JsonMessage(js) => TextFrame(Json.stringify(js))
    }
    def fromFrame(frame: BasicFrame): WSMessage = frame match {
      case TextFrame(s) => StringMessage(s)
      case BinaryFrame(a) => BinaryMessage(a)
    }
    def fromFrameDefined(clazz: Class[_]): Boolean = clazz match {
      case `textFrameClass` => true
      case `binaryFrameClass` => true
      case _ => false // shouldn't be reachable
    }
  }

  class WebSocketInActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
    override def preStart() = {
      println("User connected")
      val s = "Hello"
      val a:Array[Byte] = Array(100, 50, 30).map(_.toByte)
      out ! StringMessage(s)
      out ! JsonMessage(Json.obj("txt" -> s, "array" -> a))
      out ! BinaryMessage(a)
    }
    override def postStop() = {
      println("User discconnected")
    }
    def receive = {
      case msg: String => {
      }
      case _ =>
    }
  }

  def socket = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[String, WSMessage] { request => out =>
    Props(new WebSocketInActor(out))
  }
```