# Scala Play WebSocket - One Actor, multiple message types

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket

What I want to do is basically 1:1 this: [Scala Play Websocket - use one out actor to send both: Array[Byte] and String messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090730/scala-play-websocket-use-one-out-actor-to-send-both-arraybyte-and-string-me)

Sadly the API has changed a lot since 2.4 (I am on 2.6.0-M4 right now).

What I tried (does not compile for obvious reasons):

```
WebSocket.accept[WSMessage, WSMessage]
    {
      request =>
        ActorFlow.actorRef
        {
          out => WebSocketActor.props(out)
        }
    }


  sealed trait WSMessage
  case class StringMessage(s: String) extends WSMessage
  case class BinaryMessage(a: Array[Byte]) extends WSMessage
  case class JsonMessage(js: JsValue) extends WSMessage

  object MyMessageFlowTransformer
  {
    implicit val WSMessageFlowTransformer: MessageFlowTransformer[WSMessage, WSMessage] =
    {
      new MessageFlowTransformer[WSMessage, WSMessage]
      {
        def transform(flow: Flow[WSMessage, WSMessage, _]) =
        {
          AkkaStreams.bypassWith[Message, WSMessage, Message](Flow[Message] collect
          {
            case StringMessage(s) => Left(s)
            case BinaryMessage(b) => Left(b)
            case JsonMessage(j) => Left(j)
            case _ => Right(CloseMessage(Some(CloseCodes.Unacceptable)))
          })(flow map WSMessage.apply)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I am somewhat lost. `play.api.http.websocket.Message` is a sealed trait, and probably for a good reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `MessageFlowTransformer[Either[String, Array[Byte]], Either[String, Array[Byte]]]`:

```scala
type WSMessage = Either[String, Array[Byte]]

implicit val mixedMessageFlowTransformer: MessageFlowTransformer[WSMessage, WSMessage] = {
  new MessageFlowTransformer[WSMessage, WSMessage] {
    def transform(flow: Flow[WSMessage, WSMessage, _]) = {
      AkkaStreams.bypassWith[Message, WSMessage, Message](Flow[Message].collect {
        case BinaryMessage(data) => Left(Right(data.toArray))
        case TextMessage(text) => Left(Left(text))
      })(flow map {
        case Right(data) => BinaryMessage.apply(ByteString.apply(data))
        case Left(text) => TextMessage.apply(text)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And if I wanted more than 2? Like also Json or xml

Comment: A WebSocket `Message` is either a `BinaryMessage` or a `TextMessage` on-the-wire. How do you expect to know if its **content** is either a JSON or an XML? The only thing I could think of is to de-serialize it and fallback to a plain text/binary on failure.